# Why is send_data not working unless I manually enter the address in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, pdf, png

I am using Rails 5.

Why won't send_data display itself?
It worked when I manually entered in the browser. 
http://localhost:3000/docfiles/show/59f9f6a651d2f52dc080116c

Do I need a layout or view for this def?

Here is my hard code (only one f1.png for this question):

```
def show     
  data= read_binary('./upload/f1.png')
  send_data(data, :filename=>'f1.png', :type=>'image/png', :disposition=>"inline")   
end
```

mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "image/png", :png
```

Then display at browser bar:
    http://localhost:3000/docfiles/show/59f9f6a651d2f52dc080116c
Error: undefined and no image display.

[image]

But if I [Enter] (without any extension), then the image file shown up.!
[image]

Comment: Please add more information to your question, including more code. What are you trying to achieve? Share the complete code for any relevant models, views, and controllers.

Comment: try `send_data(data.read, :filename=>doc.filename, :type=>doc.content_type, :disposition=>"inline")`

Comment: Then: ====>  NoMethodError - undefined method `read' for #<String:0x00007fbe611d4be8>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller def just remove send_data and created view with link_to_blank 
(I found same problem if use link_to)

```
      %td= link_to_blank align_text(doc.filename), :controller=>"mycontroller", :action=>:listdocument, :id=>doc.id
```